# WooCommerce get_name into ACF Repeater Field

Tags: woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I am facing the following challenge right now, if someone could help met out I would really appreciate it.

My goal is to save WooCommerce order data in an ACF Repeater field. The code I use is as followed:

```
function create_post_after_order( $order_id ) {
  if (  $order_id instanceof WC_Order ){
    return;
  }
    
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  $order_items = $order->get_items(); 
    
    foreach ( $order_items as $item_id => $item_data ) {
    $product_name.= $item_data->get_name();
    $product_id.= $item_data->get_product_id();
    $product_quantity.= $item_data->get_quantity();
}
    
    $new_post = array(
    'post_title' => "Order {$order_id}",
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_author' => $user_ID,
    'post_type' => 'groeiproces',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
  );    
  $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

// repeater field with one subfield
$classs_field_key = 'field_61645b866cbd6';
$classs_subfield_key = 'field_61645b916cbd7';
$classs_items = array($product_name, $product_name);

foreach ($classs_items as $classs_items_value) {
    $classs_value[] = array(
    $classs_subfield_key => $classs_items_value);
    update_field($classs_field_key, $classs_value, $post_id);
}
    
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'create_post_after_order', 10, 1 );
```

The problem is that this combines the order data en saves it to the repeater fields.
[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KR7Y9.png)

Want I want is that every productname gets saved in a new repeater field.
[Ideal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1cn2.png)

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

With the help of Naveen I was able to upgrade my code to the following:

```
//Creër post met orderdetails na bestelling

function create_post_after_order( $order_id ) {
  if (  $order_id instanceof WC_Order ){
    return;
  }

//Zoek de order ID's met bijbehorende items
     
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  $order_items = $order->get_items(); 

//Loop door alle orders voor de onderstaande orderdata
    
    foreach ( $order_items as $item_id => $item_data ) {
    $product_ids[]       = $item_data->get_product_id(); // ID's van de producten
    $product_names[]     = $item_data->get_name(); // Namen van de producten
    $product_quantities[] = $item_data->get_quantity(); // Aantal van de producten
    $product_prices[] = $product->get_price(); //Prijs per product
    $ordeline_subtotals[]     = $item_data->get_subtotal(); //Subtotaal van de orderregels

}

//Maak een nieuwe post aan
    
    $new_post = array(
    'post_title' => "Order {$order_id}", // Definieer titel van de post
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), // Voeg publicatiedatum toe
    'post_author' => $user_ID, // Definieer de klant als auteur
    'post_type' => 'groeiproces', // Definieer CPT
    'post_status' => 'publish', // Publiceer post
  );    
  $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
    
//Verbind de ACF velden

    $orderdetails_key = 'field_61645b866cbd6';
    $product_id_key = 'field_6166a67234fa3';
    $product_name_key = 'field_61645b916cbd7';
    $product_quantity_key = 'field_6165bd2101987';
    $product_price_key = 'field_6166a68134fa4';
    $ordeline_subtotal_key = 'field_6166a68934fa5';
    $product_id = $product_ids;
    $product_name = $product_names;
    $product_quantity = $product_quantities;
    $product_price = $product_prices;
    $ordeline_subtotal = $ordeline_subtotals;

//Save de orderdata in het ACF repeater field

foreach ($product_id as $index => $product_id) {
    $orderdetails_value[] = array(
    $product_id_key => $product_id, 
    $product_name_key => $product_name[$index],
    $product_quantity_key => $product_quantity[$index],
    $product_price_key => $product_price[$index],
    $ordeline_subtotal_key => $ordeline_subtotal[$index],
);
    update_field( $orderdetails_key, $orderdetails_value, $post_id );
}
    
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'create_post_after_order', 10, 1 );
```

This gives me the following situation which is great.

[current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp2Cj.png)

The only thing I am still looking for is the product price from the order. I am not totally sure if it is able to get this, as I only found the active price option online. Maybe it would be possible to just divide the $ordeline_subtotals by the $product_quantities.

Anyone who does know how to set this up?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find two issues in your code:

1. You are concatenating $product_name instead of putting them in an array.
2. You are updating the field inside a for loop instead of outside the loop.

These two issues are fixed in the below code... take note of $product_names as array and then we loop this array at the end to create values for your repeater field.

```
function create_post_after_order( $order_id ) {
  if (  $order_id instanceof WC_Order ){
    return;
  }
    
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  $order_items = $order->get_items(); 
    
    
    foreach ( $order_items as $item_id => $item_data ) {
    $product_names[]     = $item_data->get_name();
    $product_ids[]       = $item_data->get_product_id();
    $product_quantities[] = $item_data->get_quantity();
}
    
    $new_post = array(
    'post_title' => "Order {$order_id}",
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_author' => $user_ID,
    'post_type' => 'groeiproces',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
  );    
  $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

// repeater field with one subfield
$classs_field_key = 'field_61645b866cbd6';
$classs_subfield_key = 'field_61645b916cbd7';
$classs_items = $product_names;

foreach ($classs_items as $classs_items_value) {
    $classs_value[] = array(
    $classs_subfield_key => $classs_items_value);
}

update_field($classs_field_key, $classs_value, $post_id);

    
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'create_post_after_order', 10, 1 );
```

Pls note that I have slightly altered the array variable names (example $product_name is now $product_names with 's' in it and same applies to other variables).

EDIT (answering to additional question asked by the OP):

To get the price of the product, we first need to get an instance of the corresponding product object from the order. This is done as follows inside the foreach loop:

```
$product_details = $item_data->get_product();

// Get the product price that customer paid
$product_price          = $product_details->get_price(); 

//Get sale price (i.e discounted price, if it exists)
$product_regular_price  = $product_details->get_sale_price(); 

//Regular price.
$product_sale_price     = $product_details->get_regular_price();
```

Assuming you may need just the product price only, then your foreach loop may look like this:

```
foreach ( $order_items as $item_id => $item_data ) {
    $product_ids[]       = $item_data->get_product_id(); // ID's van de producten
    $product_names[]     = $item_data->get_name(); // Namen van de producten
    $product_quantities[] = $item_data->get_quantity(); // Aantal van de producten

    $product_details = $item_data->get_product();

    // Get the product price that customer paid
    $product_prices[]          = $product_details->get_price(); 

    $ordeline_subtotals[]     = $item_data->get_subtotal(); //Subtotaal van de orderregels

}
```

You can then use the `$product_price` in your repeater field's foreach loop.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code worked like a charm. You really made my day!

Comment: Hi Naveen, I am struggling with one last problem, check my updated post. Could you help me with that?
Thanks a lot

Comment: First step is to get product object. `$product_details = item_details->get_product()` will give you product object which can then give price as `$product_details->get_price();` I have added this to my response above.

Comment: Thanks Naveen. I fixed it! Could not thank you enough for your help!